# PIVOT, multiple aggregations? Multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, procedure

This is what we have so far.

This is our input Data we have now.

```
SCOREQuali_39    K_Sperr_Cod       DB2_TOTAL
    NULL            0                NULL
    NULL            0                690.226684288121
    NULL            5                NULL
    NULL            13               -20.6408152008628
    G               0               -54.580159556553
    NULL            5                -5.37403744493121
    H               0                3593.56170469699
    NULL            5                NULL
    G               0                NULL
    F               0                NULL
    G               0                -62.6926387195259
    NULL            5                NULL
    NULL            5                NULL
    H               0                1408.52983029661
```

This is our SQL Code we got so far.

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE (
                            @columns + ',[' + [SCOREQuali_39] + ']',
                            '[' + [SCOREQuali_39] + ']'
                           )
  FROM [dbo].[KXEN]
 GROUP BY [SCOREQuali_39]
 ORDER BY [SCOREQuali_39]

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
SET @query = 'SELECT *
               FROM (SELECT [K_Sperr_Cod],
                            [SCOREQuali_39],
                            [DB2_TOTAL]
                       FROM [dbo].[KXEN]
                     ) PIV
              PIVOT (
                     SUM([DB2_TOTAL]) FOR [SCOREQuali_39] in (' + @columns + ')
                    ) AS chld'

EXECUTE (@query)
GO
```

And this comes as output from the SQL Code..

```
K_Sperr_Cod A   E   F   G   H   Z
0   255068.499500406    330873.173845716    61751973.8684996    47726691.9141684    219108948.21594 5796194.75837109
1   NULL    NULL    48104.4040577828    24257.7279835226    83930.9535365729    7166.90224131628
2   NULL    NULL    4200.02651139712    186.299907511524    21404.4251675196    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    90.6788153645106    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL    3299.17171760959    6898.57843394471    34617.9499761113    141.569391059137
6   NULL    NULL    8223.99222164943    NULL    36399.7235520784    NULL
7   NULL    9431.17125064557    49192.2298488292    27022.0434106792    259157.952646459    2613.38080876173
8   NULL    NULL    5085.36984841527    4579.52341830547    45967.6453351029    NULL
9   NULL    NULL    5016.61173948202    4684.68398880511    6507.85505033565    76.5867787484384
10  NULL    NULL    32637.6131091879    16337.6524219655    156041.485722849    NULL
11  NULL    NULL    1959.61759693503    NULL    175.003852737077    NULL
12  NULL    NULL    49377.6994079961    9025.28132917931    67220.6009906211    213.921132670872
13  NULL    NULL    2023.68914784688    1011.24171909977    3508.66494748362    NULL
14  NULL    NULL    9894.59491921946    3660.72246455194    26979.7285260416    33.2429911696158
15  NULL    NULL    68.5418213084175    NULL    13888.9894847372    NULL
16  NULL    NULL    62.6439310312258    177.563416355756    147.875800320802    NULL
```

The idea is to be able to use more than one column (SCOREQuali_39 only now)
any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean you want to use more than one column `SCOREQuali_39`?  can you post a sample of the expected results?

Comment: It is hard to determine your actual question. Can you please give us more detail regarding your question?

Comment: Hello, yes sorry. The idea is to have an application, eventually, that allows us to select any column, as a column, row or data, to run pivot operations over them and display the output in a grid much like Excel->Pivot does.

Right now we've managed to build a query for testing that, kinda, returns data we can work with but I'm still working on writing a "query builder class" to make these queries programmatically.

The query is as follows:
http://pastebin.com/B0qUZGt8

( not sure if i'm allowed to post a link but it's quite long compared to the max length of a post so i've used pastebin )